# Making a domain conditional on other values in the table

Tags: postgresql, constraint, ddl, domain

How can I define or change a domain based on another attribute value?

F.e. domain for salary is a numeric value > 500. But if a date the person was hired > January 1st, 2013, then the salary must be > 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try to solve that with a [`DOMAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) since that cannot reference other columns. Use a [`CHECK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) constraint instead:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_min_salary
CHECK (salary > 1000 OR hired < '2013-01-01' AND salary > 500);
```

- Define the column `NOT NULL` in addition to disallow `NULL` values.
- Using the [IS0 8601 format for the date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE), which is valid with any locale and the recommended form.
- Note how I inverted your logic to arrive at a simpler form.
- I wrote `hired < '2013-01-01'` on purpose, suspecting that your phrase `hired > January 1st, 2013` is off by one.
- Be aware of [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). `AND` binds before `OR`.

**If** you are building on a domain that already demands `value > 500`, you can simplify the `CHECK` constraint to:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_min_salary
CHECK (salary > 1000 OR hired < '2013-01-01');
```

Comment: You mentioned operator precedence, but I think it would be cleaner to explicitly use parentheses to indicated the intended behaviour. When I see AND together with OR and no parentheses I always wonder if the author intended what it means (obviously not with your answers though ;) )

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Good point. Personally, though, I am not a fan of noise parentheses: those make *me* wonder whether the author knows his stuff. Maybe an added comment (like in my answer) can help avoid confusion.

Comment: I hate noise parentheses as well ;) - although I don't consider it noise in cases like this (but I do acknowledge that this is highly subjective)

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, it may help to think of it like this

- *Table check constraints* - used to ensure data validity on the **row** and *all* of the rows columns.
- *Domain constraints* - used to ensure data validity on the **type**, regardless of where used.

You wanted to use the wrong tool for the job.